# could not greet: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = exit status 1

Tags: grpc-go

I was just starting out in grpc and I was just following the quick start guide of grpc in Golang. So I just started the greeter_server main.go file and it works fine but when I run greeter_client main.go file then I get an error

> could not greet: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc =  exit status 1

I am using Windows 11 OS.

Answer (score 0):

"This means that whatever operation you are trying to do is not supported or enabled on the gRPC Service you are calling into. See [https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md."](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md.%22)